# NPE from CglibAopProxy while using @Async annotation on method

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous

I'm getting NPE when trying to use @Async annotation for the method which sends emails.

```
@Async
@Override
public void sendCloseShiftInfoFromText(Double cashBox, Double cache, Double bankKart, Double payWithCard,
                                       Double allPrice, Collection<? extends User> users, Double shortage) {
    MimeMessagePreparator[] mimeMessages = new MimeMessagePreparator[users.size()];
    int messageNum = 0;
    for (User user : users) {
        String email = user.getEmail();
        if (email == null) {
            continue;
        }
        mimeMessages[messageNum++] = mimeMessage -> {
            MimeMessageHelper messageHelper = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage);
            messageHelper.setFrom(properties.getMail().getSender());
            messageHelper.setTo(email);
            messageHelper.setSubject(closeShiftSubject);
            String html = htmlService.getCloseShiftFromText(closeShiftText, cashBox, cache, bankKart, payWithCard,
                    allPrice, closeShiftView, users, shortage);
            messageHelper.setText(html, true);
        };
    }
    if (messageNum == 0) {
        return;
    }
    javaMailSender.send(mimeMessages);
}
```

Here is the Exception I'm getting:

```
20:24:57.565 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] ERROR org.springframework.web - 
Asynchronous Exception :Could not prepare mail; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
20:24:57.565 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] ERROR org.springframework.web - Method name :sendCloseShiftInfoFromText
20:24:57.565 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] ERROR org.springframework.web - Parameter :121246.0
20:24:57.566 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] ERROR org.springframework.web - Parameter :0.0
20:24:57.566 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] ERROR org.springframework.web - Parameter :0.0
20:24:57.566 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] ERROR org.springframework.web - Parameter :0.0
20:24:57.566 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] ERROR org.springframework.web - Parameter :0.0
20:24:57.566 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] ERROR org.springframework.web - Parameter :[com.cafe.crm.models.user.User@4727bacf]
20:24:57.566 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] ERROR org.springframework.web - Parameter :121246.0
```

I tried to find the source of NPE. After reaching "`String html = htmlService.getCloseShiftFromText...`" the following method is invocated:

```
@Override
public String getCloseShiftFromText(String text, Double cashBox, Double cache, Double bankKart, Double payWithCard,
                                    Double allPrice, String view, Collection<? extends User> recipients,
                                    Double shortage) {
    List<User> usersOnShift = shiftService.getUsersOnShift();
    ...
}
```

From the line `List<User> usersOnShift = shiftService.getUsersOnShift();` the debugger goes to CglibAopProxy class:

```
    @Override
    public Object intercept(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args, MethodProxy methodProxy) throws Throwable {
        Object oldProxy = null;
        boolean setProxyContext = false;
        Class<?> targetClass = null;
        Object target = null;
        try {
            if (this.advised.exposeProxy) {
                // Make invocation available if necessary.
                oldProxy = AopContext.setCurrentProxy(proxy);
                setProxyContext = true;
            }
            // May be null. Get as late as possible to minimize the time we
            // "own" the target, in case it comes from a pool...
            target = getTarget();
            if (target != null) {
                targetClass = target.getClass();
            }
            List<Object> chain = this.advised.getInterceptorsAndDynamicInterceptionAdvice(method, targetClass);
            Object retVal;
            // Check whether we only have one InvokerInterceptor: that is,
            // no real advice, but just reflective invocation of the target.
            if (chain.isEmpty() && Modifier.isPublic(method.getModifiers())) {
                // We can skip creating a MethodInvocation: just invoke the target directly.
                // Note that the final invoker must be an InvokerInterceptor, so we know
                // it does nothing but a reflective operation on the target, and no hot
                // swapping or fancy proxying.
                Object[] argsToUse = AopProxyUtils.adaptArgumentsIfNecessary(method, args);
                retVal = methodProxy.invoke(target, argsToUse);
            }
            else {
                // We need to create a method invocation...
                retVal = new CglibMethodInvocation(proxy, target, method, args, targetClass, chain, methodProxy).proceed();
            }
            retVal = processReturnType(proxy, target, method, retVal);
            return retVal;
        }
        finally {
            if (target != null) {
                releaseTarget(target);
            }
            if (setProxyContext) {
                // Restore old proxy.
                AopContext.setCurrentProxy(oldProxy);
            }
        }
    }
```

Somehow despite `setProxyContext == false` the debugger goes to `AopContext.setCurrentProxy(oldProxy);` line and that's the source of NPE.
Below is screenshot from debugger

[image]

The code is working fine without the annotation.

I would really appreciate if someone could explain why the last piece of code works the way it does. It also would be nice to find the solution.

Comment: I doubt it actually is going to that line despite what the debugger is telling you. Make sure you are looking at the proper sources for the right version of the code you are using. I suspect the issue is due some final methods or non public methods being called leading to a call on the proxy instead of the actual class through the proxy.

Answer (score 1):

M. Deinum thanks for the advice. As it turned out somehow the debugger was misleading. I found the actual method which was giving the exception by printing to console; this method was making a call to Spring SecurityContext. As the method was marked with @Async it was running in a new thread and the context was not authenticated.
The solution is to change SecurityContextHolder strategy from default MODE_THREADLOCAL to MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL.